# Suspend-to-RAM breaks ACPI thermals

Tags: suspend, acpi, fan, sensors

Sometimes after waking from suspend-to-RAM, my ACPI thermal sensor is "frozen" on a fixed, mostly higher temperature. The rest of the sensors are working fine, but since the fan speed is apparently controlled from the ACPI temperature reading, it is kinda annoying and might be bad if it ever freezes at a lower temperature.

Output of `sensors`:

```
asus-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
cpu_fan:     3900 RPM
temp1:       +6280.4°C  

soc_dts0-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +47.0°C  

BAT0-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
in0:           7.60 V  

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +75.0°C  (crit = +104.0°C)

soc_dts1-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +49.0°C  

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +44.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:       +44.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 2:       +47.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 3:       +47.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
```

Also, what's that ISA temp1 at 6000 degrees?
Machine is an ASUS X553MA running Linux 5.7.6-arch1-1.

Answer (score 0):

File a bug report at https://bugzilla.kernel.org/ as this definitely looks like a bug which needs to be fixed.

Posting dmesg output along with your bug report would be pertinent.